# Receiving DecodingError.dataCorrupted error when decoding JSON file

Tags: arrays, json

I'm trying to create/decode JSON for the first time, so hoping this is a rookie mistake where someone can easily put me on the right track.  I'm trying to do something very basic - loading data from a JSON file to fill an array of a class with a single property.

Here's my code:

BUNDLE EXTENSION TO DECODE JSON FILE:

```
extension Bundle {
    
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String, dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate, keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy

        do {
            return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to missing key '\(key.stringValue)' not found – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to type mismatch – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let type, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to missing \(type) value – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(_) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle because it appears to be invalid JSON")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

CLASS DEFINITION:

```
class Category: Codable, ObservableObject {
    var name: String = "Uncategorized"
}
```

CALL TO DECODE THE JSON FILE (this is what generates the DecodingError.dataCorrupted error):

```
let categories: [Category] = Bundle.main.decode([Category].self, from: "Categories.json")
```

FORMAT OF JSON FILE:

```
[
{“name” : “Category 1”},
{“name” : “Category 2”},
{“name” : “Category 3”},
{“name” : “Category 4”},
{“name” : “Category 5”}
]
```

Is there an error in my JSON file format, which is intended to load an array of [Category]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was not the format of the data within the file, but rather the format of the actual file itself.  I copied an example of a working JSON file, renamed it, loaded it into my bundle, and entered my data in the structure noted above, and then the decoder worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

test json :
http://jsonselector.com/

your json is not good